# How to send Crashlytics log

Tags: android, crashlytics

I am using Crashlytics (now known as Fabric) in my app.

It works well when the app crashes. I can find the issue on the dashboard.

I am trying to use the logging. Something like:

```
Crashlytics.log(Log.WARN,MYTAG,"Error message");
```

I am not able to send this log in the dashboard. I have just tried to add something like:

```
Crashlytics.logException(new RuntimeException("Fake exception"));
```

but it doesn't send the log.

**Can Crashlytics send the log?**

Comment: Hi Gabriele, we do it using the second option you posted and it works well. The logs appear on the dashboard as NON-FATAL. It can teake some time to appear. Here is the code we use: Crashlytics.logException(new Throwable("No response received"));

Comment: Here you have the docs: http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202805-logging-caught-exceptions

Comment: Hope you are searching here - `Crashlytics - >All logged exceptions will appear as "non-fatal" issues in the Crashlytics dashboard`. [Crashlytics Caught Exceptions](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202805-logging-caught-exceptions)

Comment: @lluismontero Thanks it works, but as described by bharat the logs are sent when the app restarts.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are sending the Log properly. But see what Official doc says [Logging Caught Exceptions](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202805-logging-caught-exceptions)

> All logged exceptions will appear as "non-fatal" issues in the Crashlytics dashboard.
>
> To reduce your users' network traffic, Crashlytics batches logged exceptions together and **sends them the next time the app launches.** If you don't see logged exceptions in your Crashlytics web dashboard, try restarting your app!

Comment: You are right.
Restarting the app I can see the logs in dashboard.

Comment: But you can see the message? Or just an exception?

Answer (score 13):

In **Android**, send a custom crash by using

```
Crashlytics.logException(new RuntimeException("Fake exception"));
```

Then restart your application

In **Crashlytics**, select the Non-Fatals

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On newer versions of Crashlytics, you need to use these functions:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log("Your message goes here")
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(RuntimeException("Your message goes here"))
```

**Edit**:
As @Peter mentioned in the comments, using `log` alone will not work and you have to use `recordException` function to bundle your log message along with the exception

Comment: I think that using `log`, error won't get reported. If you use `recordException` after, your log will probably get attached to the exception as metadata, which is not correct.