# Log Non-fatal errors on Crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

On iOS it's possible to use [recordError(error)](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/logged-errors.html) to log non-fatal errors on Crashlytics but apparently this feature is not available for Android.

The only alternative I found is to use [logException(e)](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/caught-exceptions.html). 
I manage errors on my app and I want to log when specifics errors codes are returned. So, on Crashlytics I'd like the non-fatal errors to be referenced by the errorCode. But using the *logException(e)* method, errors are referenced by the method where *logException(e)* has been called.

How can I do that?

Comment: you can check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45071033/5381331. Hope it help

Comment: So many detailed answers with upvotes, yet none actually answer the question...

Answer (score 49):

What I do in order to report a non-fatal issue is to [log an exception](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/caught-exceptions.html) using the following code (remember you can throw any subclass of `Exception`):

`Crashlytics.logException(new Exception("My custom error message"));`

Comment: However this doesn't upload the reports until an app restart, unlike iOS' `recordError`.

Comment: @DarkNeuron any solution of this? I want to log exception immediately

Comment: @ysfcyln Not that I know of :(

Comment: `recordError` waits for the next app launch as well. Per https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=ios#log-excepts "Crashlytics lets you record non-fatal exceptions and sends them to you the next time your app launches."

Answer (score 23):

For those who have [migrated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android) from Fabric-Crashlytics SDK to Firebase-Crashlytics SDK, the new way of logging non-critical exceptions or exceptions which have been caught in a try-catch block is this -

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e)
```

To add additional data fields to the crash report you can key-value pairs before logging the exception like this

```
val crashlytics = FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance()
crashlytics.setCustomKey("position", 1)
crashlytics.setCustomKey("marker_mode", "hidden")
crashlytics.setCustomKey("direction_shown", true)
```

To add some log messages,

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log("Reached breakpoint 2")
```

Answer (score 18):

You can also use Crashlytics below features to provide more information.

**Logging Non-Fatal Events:**

```
try {
  myMethodThatThrows();
} catch (Exception e) {
  Crashlytics.logException(e);
  // handle your exception here!
}
```

**Add some more messages:**

```
Crashlytics.log(int priority, String tag, String msg);
Crashlytics.log("Higgs-Boson detected! Bailing out...");
```

**Also you can provide some user information:**

```
void Crashlytics.setUserIdentifier(String identifier);
void Crashlytics.setUserName(String name);
void Crashlytics.setUserEmail(String email);
```

Comment: Crashlytics.log("msg") is good for only as an additional complement for a possible future exception, otherwise, a dev will not find it on the Crashltyics dashboard.

Comment: If this is coming from 'io.fabric' it has been deprecated, don't use this.. Use FirebaseCrahlytics instead.

Answer (score 2):

As per the latest version of Crashlytics [library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android#add-plugin) 2.9.2 .. You can log [non-fatal exception](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#log-excepts) through this code

```
Firebase.crashlytics.recordException(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to record non fatel error log in your app
In my case i used it as logging all the request other then 200 from server.
you can use like this as well.
For this you can use just this after all the configurations

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.log('Here is My custom Error for it ');
```